# Paging in asp.net Listview control

Tags: asp.net

How do get the paging functionality (like we have in asp.net gridview) in Listview control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the pager control

see this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20211031102325/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you use datasource simply drag a DataPager control inside the `<LayoutTemplate>` tag.