# C# listview paging question

Tags: c#, asp.net, datapager

In Listview, if I want to use the paging feature, how can i increase the amount of rows shown for each page? I would like to increase the current rows form say 10 to 35.

Comment: paging feature? Are you taking about using a `DataPager` in ASP.Net?

Comment: perhaps the other answers will help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597384/paging-in-asp-net-listview-control

Comment: In listview there is not such a property with which you set the Page Size. Page Size property is available in GridView. For ListView you can use the DataPager Control with the ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are talking about ASP.net you could use a DataPager control that allows you to set up all the common Paging properties(PageSize,etc)

http://thibautvs.com/blog/?p=718

https://web.archive.org/web/20210125144848/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use the `PageSize` property as in:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25">
```

**EDIT**
I just saw that you're talking about `ListView`. In that case, [here is an article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/100_Paging_in_ListView_in_ASPNet_35.aspx) that describes paging for `ListView`s.

Basically you add a `DataPager`, which again has a `PageSize` property. It is well described in the linked article.

Comment: He asked for listview not grid view.